# Where can I ask for word suggestions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was about to post a question asking what to call something, when I noticed that other people had already asked a number of questions starting with "What do I call a...", which were closed as opinion-based. Where is the correct place to ask these questions then?

My specific question, which I have not posted, was what word would best be used to describe an application without a web-interface, to differentiate it from the online SAAS programs that are now what is commonly referred to by the terms application or program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

Comment: I disagree about the duplicate - the question states that the question is known to be off-topic, but wants to know _where_ to ask such a question. Normally a question asking "on which site do I ask?" belongs at [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), but seeing that it is asking in the context of Programmers.SE scope, we can probably leave this question as-is.

Answer (score 4):

[Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) is probably a good place.

You will find a ton of opinions and perspectives there and perhaps quickly see why they are not great fits for the main site :)